# Текст в ArrayList

Tags: java, android, массивы

Есть `ArrayList`:

```
word
word
word
```

с неизвестным размером, его я перевожу в `String` (то есть получается `[word, word, word]`) и отправляю запрос на сервер. Спустя секунду прилетает ответ с этой же строкой, получается `[word1, word1, word1]`.

Как мне эту строку перевести обратно в `ArrayList` c видом:

```
word1
word1
word1
```

Comment: почему бы не воспользоваться сериализацией для этого?

Comment: @tym32167 сериализацией чего?

Comment: вашего списка в текст и обратно

Comment: спрошу по другому. Как десериализовать строку обратно в ArrayList в таком случае?

Comment: вы может покажете код какой-то? не видя как вы отправляете запрос и как формируете список сложно помочь

Comment: что если ваше слово будет содержать запятую или квадратную скобку или пробелы по краям? В таком случае вы никак не сможете преобразовать текст в изначальный список слов.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать метод `split()` класса `String`

Например:

```
String str = "word1, word1, word1"
String[] words = str.split(",")
```

[Здесь](https://javadevblog.com/primer-ispol-zovaniya-metoda-split-na-java.html) есть больше примеров.

Если там будут какие-то еще ненужные символы вы можете их заменить методом `replace()` класса `String`. Скорее всего вам это надо сделать то вызова метода split(). Т.е. убрать все лишние символы и оставить только сепараторы (это могут быть и пробелы вместо запятых. Например вы можете убрать регуляркой ВСЕ символы, а по пробелам сделать `split()`)

Например так:

```
str.replaceAll("[|]"), "") //todo вот тут могу ошибаться, я плохо помню регулярные выражения
```

Вот [здесь](http://www.quizful.net/post/Java-RegExp) вы можете посмотреть как работать с регулярками в Java

**UPD:**

Вот так можно из строки убрать ВСЕ символы. В вашем случае останутся только пробелы, которые вы можете указать как сепараторы:

```
String str = yourString.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]","");
```

**UPD2:**

Как правильно заметил **@tym32167** в комменатариях. Если у вас всегда скобки первым и последним символом вы можете воспользоваться методом `subtring()`

```
str.substring(0, array.length -1 )
```

Comment: там еще квадратные скобки по краям. То есть автору еще и substring пригодится.

Comment: Добавил коммент с регулярным выражением, но не очень уверен в правильности. Если кто-то добавит что-то - Welcome

Comment: Ну судя по формату, что автор показал, у вас нет необходимости в регулярке, достаточно только отрезать первый и последний символы строки.

Comment: Ну чтоб их отрезать нужно либо дважды вызывать что-то типа str.replace("[", "") или лучше написать регулярку и отрезать сразу все ненужные символы. Ему ж нужно выпилить и пробелы по идее.

Comment: не, чтобы парвый и последний символ убрать достаточно substring - это гораздо быстрее регулярки. Про пробелы кстати вопрос вопросов - а что если в самом слове есть пробел?

Comment: Да есть еще subString, как вы правильно заметили. И наверно если всегда строго 1ый и последний символ то это рабочее решение

Comment: Ну надо смотреть конкретный кейс. Потому, что вариантов может быть миллион и пачка=)

Comment: Согласен. Я по сути про это писал под вопросом.